# How to run a WP7 app in background without periodical delays?

Tags: windows-phone-7, whatsapp

I know there are are background tasks, but they have the restriction to only be run approximately every 25 minutes. I wonder how Apps like "Whats App" or "LINE" managed to solve this problem, because a message receiver almost instantly receives a notification, even if the app is not opened...

Comment: Push notifications and background agents are two completely distinct mechanisms.

Comment: Yes, but what my question is: What is happening on a push event? Does the OS handle it and show some notification to the user? Or does the app automatically get invoked?

Comment: Push notifications will be received even when your app is not running. By clicking on the toast, you can start your application. So I guess the answer to your question is, the app is in no way running in the background (to receive the toast). If your app is running in foreground while you receive a toast, then you have to process it.